# Convert Map to URL with parameters

Tags: java, android

Do you know of any utility class/library, that can convert Map into URL-friendly query string?

Example:

```
I have a map:
- "param1"=12,
- "param2"="cat"
```

I want to get:

```
param1=12&param2=cat
```

final output

```
relativeUrl+param1=12&param2=cat
```

Comment: please do not copy existing questions just to get more answers to the original question. When you have more reputation you can add a bounty to the original question to make it more visible/"bump it". I have merged the answers into the original question. Please don't do this again.